# Can we have a RSS feed based on a particular user's answers, comments, and/or upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, usability, feed

I have found that there are a handful of high-rep users [I'm looking at you [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)] whose answers to a broad variety of questions are enlightening and educational. Often I find myself browsing through their answers just as an opportunity to learn something.

I know that I would find it useful (and a time-saver) to be able to get an RSS feed of all of the question, answers and comments these folks are posting, as a way to keep up with interesting content, rather than having to search on this manually. It may also be interesting to see which answers these folks upvote.

What does the MSO community think of this? Am I out on a limb here or what.

Answer (score 2):

You can already get most of this in the recent tab of the user's profile. There is an RSS button down at the bottom of that page with the feed's link.

This is not going to include voting of course, since voting is anonymous.

For instance this is mine:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/5640/recent

Comment: **Beat me to it.**

Comment: It also doesn't include a feed of comments on other answers.

Comment: If you don't hang up that battery and get off the internet I will beat you for sure. You tivo'd Springer, right?

Comment: @LBushkin: The feed includes all comments that the user makes AFAIK.

Comment: It would also be helpful if the RSS feed fro the user page included the text of the question.

Comment: @LBushkin: I just checked mine.  It includes, for example, my comment on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/does-the-so-development-team-use-fogbugz/5694#5694

Comment: @LBushkin: Have you tried this feed out yet? It is amazingly simple, and you are asking for things that are either already implemented or defy the idea of RSS.

Comment: Yes, I looked into it, and it does track comments. I was mistaken.