# RSS feed of user's posts across the network?

Tags: discussion, feed

The answer to [Can we have a RSS feed based on a particular user's answers, comments, and/or upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5797/157730) shows how to get a RSS feed with a particular user's questions and answers on a particular site, through the "user feed" link at the bottom of the profile page on each site.

However, I would like a RSS feed that aggregates *all* my questions and answers *across the network*. Something like a RSS version of [the Activity -> Posts tab on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/225818/michael-kjorling?tab=activity). I tried the obvious of adapting the URL to use the stackexchange.com domain, but only got a *not found* response back.

Does something like this exist, and if so how do I access it? Or would I have to cobble something together manually by combining feeds from each site to achieve my desired result?

Comment: Personally, I'd rather have questions and answers (and maybe comments and getting badges and so on) separated into different feeds. I think I can handle the aggregation on my own. This would make it really nice to aggregate into something if IFTTT, though, to automatically post questions / answers to Twitter, or maybe to LinkedIn for various sites that are professional, and so on.