# how can I generate/access RSS feed for Inbox of my network profile

Tags: support, feed

I want an RSS feed for my [Inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/5351271/xypha?tab=inbox) of my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5351271/xypha),

an alternative or bonus would be an RSS feed for my "Achievements", so that I don't have to login to the website via a browser

I have visited a few similar questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238494/rss-feed-of-users-posts-across-the-network) & many others without a solution.

I also read about [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source#), but I don't know how to make it work for me.

Is there a way I can generate an RSS feed, maybe say using a rss feed generator from another website?

Comment: You missed the exact duplicate, which contains the answer you want.